# Is it fine for two different regression lines on the same dataset to have the same MSE?

Tags: regression, least-squares, mean

My partner and I were doing a basic least squares regression line on some dataset. We got an intercept and coefficient that were different, but our MSE on the test dataset was the same. Is this a thing?
For some reason I had always thought there was only one regression line that minimized MSE, but I guess I was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you both performed your regression and testing on the same subsets of data?

Linear regression with least squares is a convex optimisation problem, so you should get the same line.

An exception would be performing regression on a single data point (two parameters, slope and intercept, but only one observation). In this case any line that passes through the point would be optimal.

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206115/convexity-of-linear-regression) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295343/usefulness-of-convexity-of-linear-regression-when-there-is-no-closed-form-soluti) also.